# Use org.joda.time.LocalDateTime with Querydsl

Tags: java, spring, jpa, jodatime, querydsl

I´m having problems with querydsl using as parameter org.joda.time.LocalDateTime

```java
    public BooleanBuilder createFilter() {
        BooleanBuilder builder = new BooleanBuilder();

        ...

        LocalDate date = dateService.stringToDate(filters.plannedDate);
        builder.and(QRealizableTask.realizableTask.plannedDate.dayOfMonth()
               .eq(date.getDayOfMonth()));
        builder.and(QRealizableTask.realizableTask.plannedDate.month()
               .eq(date.getMonthOfYear()));
        builder.and(QRealizableTask.realizableTask.plannedDate.year()
               .eq(date.getYear()));

        ...

        return builder;
    }
```

This code is supposed to work but it always returns a empty list

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the actual query that gets generated?

Comment: The query generated is "dayofmonth(realizableTask.plannedDate) = 1 && month(realizableTask.plannedDate) = 1 && year(realizableTask.plannedDate) = 2020"

Comment: And when you run that query manually, does it produce the result you're expecting?

Comment: No, the query always return an empty list if I include those lines

Comment: That most likely means there is no matching data in your DB, if "manually" constructed query that makes sense in this case also produces no data.

Comment: There are data with this date such as 
    "content": [
        {
            "id": 34095,
            "creationDate": "01-12-2019",
            "plannedDate": "01-01-2020 15:00",
            "dateRealization": null,
            "valid": true,
........

The json is too big to include complete

This datais shown if I don´t include that query

Comment: That's a bit too misterious then. In your first comment, did you give the raw query that actaully gets executed by the datasource, or just what querydsl produced?